# PHP datetime value not passing in as a argument

Tags: php

I am using the DateTime object in php to get a range of dates

However I am unable to pass in the value of the DateTime object into a function.

When i try assigning it to a variable, the variable is empty

Code as belows

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-04-11');
$test = $date1->setTime($i, 59);
echo $test;
```

Anyone any idea how do I assign the $date1 to a variable?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php

Answer (score 3):

That returns a `DateTime` object which doesn't have a `toString` method.

The above will generate a fatal error (you should really [enable errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#V85096)):

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /code/KHCgOS on line 7
>
> PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /code/KHCgOS on line 7

You should do something like:

```
echo $test->format('H:i:s d-m-Y');
```

More info: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TNHGlj

*Note: on a production machine you should also have error reporting enabled, but instead of displaying them you should log them*

Comment: Actually it's called __toString.

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
   $date1 = new DateTime('2013-04-11');
   $date1->setTime($i, 59);
   echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [DateTime::setTime function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php), it returns a DateTime object, so in order to print the value you have to use the [DateTime::format function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).  Here's an working example:

```
<?php
$i = 14;

$date1 = new DateTime('2013-04-11');
$date1->setTime($i, 59);

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

returns

```
2013-04-11 14:59:00
```